# Vertical Alignment Doesn't Work when Form is Added inside Div

Tags: html, css

I am (desperately) trying to vertically align (middle) a form in the middle of a div. I just couldn't get it to work all, so I just went back to basics, and vertically centered a div in the middle of another:

```
<div style='display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1 solid blue; margin: 0px; padding: 0; width: 300px; height: 70px;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; border: 1 solid green;'>text</div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly well. I would assume that the form would behave the same but when I add it I get some really strange results:

```
<div style='display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1 solid blue; margin: 0px; padding: 0; width: 300px; height: 70px;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; border: 1 solid green;'>text</div>
    <form style='display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;'>
        <label>Add Something:</label>
        <input type='text' value='nothing in there'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the text is centered with respect to the blue box but not the form. Worse, not adding vertical-align: middle to the form is actually changing the position of the text (green box)

```
<div style='display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1 solid blue; margin: 0px; padding: 0; width: 300px; height: 70px;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; border: 1 solid green;'>text</div>
    <form style='display: inline-block;'>
        <label>Add Something:</label>
        <input type='text' value='nothing in there'/>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]

I am lost. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually ended up embedding the form within the green box, declaring the form a table-cell and vertically centring it. It seems to work:

```
<div style='display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; border: 1 solid blue; margin: 0px; padding: 0; width: 300px; height: 70px;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; border: 1 solid green;'>
        <form style='display: table-cell; vertical-align:middle;'>
            <label>Add Something:</label>
            <input type='text' value='nothing in there'/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note: border: `1 solid blue` should be `border: 1px solid blue`.

This is because whenever you specify a width in css (as opposed to the outdated width and height attributes) you MUST specify the units (px, em, es, ex, rem etc.). The only exception is if you are setting the value to 0 which doesn't require units.

Comment: yes, thank you. It happens that on Safari, by default it uses px (and a few others do, IE ...). It's a bad habit I have when I debug. But good comment.